# React getting Maximum update depth exceeded error

Tags: reactjs

I'm performing a change password, for authError I'm getting the following error..

Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

changepassword.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { compose } from 'redux'
import {changePassword } from '../../store/actions/auth'

const styles = {
     textField: {
      fontSize: '5px'
    },

  };

class ChangePassword extends Component {
    state = {
        loading: false,
        open:false,
        message:'',
        cp_currentPassword: '',
        cp_newPassword: '',
        cp_confirmPassword: ''
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    openSnackbar = ({ message }) => {
        this.setState({
            open: true,
          message,
        });
      };
      handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let curpass=this.state.cp_currentPassword
        let newpass=this.state.cp_newPassword
        this.setState({loading:true});
        this.props.changePassword(curpass,newpass)
        this.openSnackbar({ message: 'Password changed Successfully.!' })
        }

    render() {
        const { classes, auth, authError } = this.props;
        const { loading } = this.state;
        const message = (
            <span
              id="snackbar-message-id"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.message }}
            />
          );
          if (!auth.uid) return <Redirect to='/signin' />
        return (
            <div>
                <GridContainer>
                    <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>

                        <Card>
                            <CardHeader color="warning">
                                <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Change Password</h4>
                            </CardHeader>
                            <form >
                            <GridContainer>
                            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
                                <CardBody>
                                    <GridContainer>
                                        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>

                                            <TextField
                                                id="cp_currentPassword"
                                                label="Current Password"
                                                type="password"
                                                fullWidth
                                                className={classes.textField}
                                                value={this.state.cp_currentPassword}
                                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                margin="normal"
                                                required={true}
                                            />
                                        </GridItem>

                                        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                                            <TextField
                                                id="cp_newPassword"
                                                label="New Password"
                                                type="password"
                                                fullWidth
                                                className={classes.textField}
                                                value={this.state.cp_newPassword}
                                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                margin="normal"
                                                required={true}
                                            />
                                        </GridItem>
                                        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                                            <TextField
                                                id="cp_confirmPassword"
                                                label="Confirm Password"
                                                type="password"
                                                fullWidth
                                                className={classes.textField}
                                                value={this.state.cp_confirmPassword}
                                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                margin="normal"
                                                required={true}
                                            />
                                        </GridItem>
                                    </GridContainer>


                                </CardBody>
                                <CardFooter>

                                    <Button color="warning" onClick={this.handleSubmit} disabled={loading}>
                                        {loading && <CircularProgress style={{ color: 'white', height: '20px', width: '20px', marginRight: '10px' }} />}
                                        Change Password
                      </Button>
                                </CardFooter>
                                </GridItem>
                                </GridContainer>
                            </form>
                        </Card>

                    </GridItem>


                </GridContainer>
                {authError ? this.openSnackbar({ message: '{authError}' }) : null}

<Snackbar
    open={this.state.open}
    anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
    message={message}
    variant="error"
    onClose={() => this.setState({ open: false, message: '' })}
    action={
        <IconButton
            key="close"
            aria-label="Close"
            color="inherit"
            className={classes.close}
            onClick={() => this.setState({ open: false, message: '' })}
        >
            <CloseIcon className={classes.icon} />
        </IconButton>
    }
    autoHideDuration={3000}
/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapstateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      auth: state.firebase.auth,
      authError: state.authroot.autherr
    }
  }
  const mapDispatchtoProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        changePassword: (currentPassword,newPassword) => { dispatch(changePassword(currentPassword,newPassword)) }
    }
  }
export default compose(
    withStyles(styles),
    connect(mapstateToProps,mapDispatchtoProps)
  )(ChangePassword);
```

change password action

```
export const changePassword = (currentPassword, newPassword) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
        const firebase = getFirebase();
        console.log(currentPassword);
        console.log(newPassword);
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        user.updatePassword(newPassword).then(() => {
            console.log("Password updated!");
        }).catch((error) => { 
            dispatch({ type: 'CHANGEPASSWORD_ERR', error })});
}
}
```

Comment: Could it be that the cause is with adding `onChange={this.handleChange}` to every `<TextField>`? Right now for every time you add a character in the textfield you call the `handleChange` function.

Comment: How can I handle this ?

Comment: You could process all the data at once after posting instead of individually handeling each text field. Then again isn't that what you are already doing inside the `changePassword` method? Why would you use a separate `handleChange` method on each text field. As far as I can tell I don't think that the `handleChange` method adds any value.

Comment: without handle how can i get the value of textfield in handlesubmit?

Comment: [Upon further investigation](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/how-to-work-with-forms-inputs-and-events-in-react-c337171b923b), I do recommend keeping it the way you have it. That is actually the best way. I didn't know that React handles the `onChange` propery differently than regular HTML does. I personally have never needed input values the same way you do since I've always send my form data to an API.

My bad, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating state here

```
{authError ? this.openSnackbar({ message: '{authError}' }) : null
```

that line runs multiple times, as it checks if there was auth error, if there was call `openSnackBar`, `openSnackBar` update state, which cause the component to re-render, after re-render the check happens again etc, which causes a loop. change it to the following and only call `openSnackBar` when `state.open` is false.

```
{authError && !this.state.open ? this.openSnackbar({ message: '{authError}' }) : null}
```

**EDIT**

remove authError from render and check in `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  const { authError } = this.props;

  if (authError) {
    this.openSnackbar({ message: '{authError}' });
  }
};
```

Comment: this removes the error, but i think still it is causing a loop. i cannot close the snackbar.

Comment: when you close the loop, it sets it to false, and the check happens again.

Comment: im getting the following warning in console

Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Comment: did you remove `{authError && !this.state.open ? this.openSnackbar({ message: '{authError}' }) : null}` from render?

Comment: this works, not causing any loop, but its not showung error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193817/discussion-between-junius-l-and-ansh).